# Sawtooth transaction not committed

Tags: hyperledger-sawtooth

I want to set up sawtooth with  multiple validators and PoET engines.

Initially I am trying to set up with just 1 Validator, 1 PoET engine, 1 PoET registry, and the intkey Transaction processor(set up using NodeJs SDK). When I launch the network and connect the TP, it registers. But when I submit a transaction to the rest API, the response URL says PENDING. the validator logs say block validation passed but the block is not created.

```
version: "2.1"

volumes:
  poet-shared:

services:
  shell:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-all:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-shell-default
    entrypoint: "bash -c \"\
        sawtooth keygen && \
        tail -f /dev/null \
        \""

  validator-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-validator:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-validator-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
      - 5050
      - 8800
    ports:
      - "4004:4004"
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: "bash -c \"\
        sawadm keygen --force && \
        mkdir -p /poet-shared/validator-0 || true && \
        cp -a /etc/sawtooth/keys /poet-shared/validator-0/ && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet.batch ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        cp /poet-shared/poet.batch / && \
        sawset genesis \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          -o config-genesis.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
          sawtooth.consensus.algorithm=poet \
          sawtooth.poet.report_public_key_pem=\
          \\\"$$(cat /poet-shared/simulator_rk_pub.pem)\\\" \
          sawtooth.poet.valid_enclave_measurements=$$(cat /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement) \
          sawtooth.poet.valid_enclave_basenames=$$(cat /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename) \
          -o config.batch && \
        sawset proposal create \
          -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv \
             sawtooth.poet.target_wait_time=5 \
             sawtooth.poet.initial_wait_time=25 \
             sawtooth.publisher.max_batches_per_block=100 \
          -o poet-settings.batch && \
        sawadm genesis \
          config-genesis.batch config.batch poet.batch poet-settings.batch && \
        sawtooth-validator -v \
          --bind network:tcp://eth0:8800 \
          --bind component:tcp://eth0:4004 \
          --bind consensus:tcp://eth0:5050 \
          --peering dynamic \
          --endpoint tcp://validator-0:8800 \
          --scheduler serial \
          --network-auth trust
    \""
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: "/project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/simulator:\
        /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/core"
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  rest-api-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-rest-api:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-rest-api-default-0
    expose:
      - 8008
    ports:
      - "8008:8008"
    command: |
      bash -c "
        sawtooth-rest-api \
          --connect tcp://validator-0:4004 \
          --bind rest-api-0:8008
      "
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  settings-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-settings-tp:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-settings-tp-default-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: settings-tp -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    stop_signal: SIGKILL


  poet-engine-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-engine:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-engine-0
    volumes:
      - poet-shared:/poet-shared
    command: "bash -c \"\
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement ]; then \
            poet enclave measurement >> /poet-shared/poet-enclave-measurement; \
        fi && \
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename ]; then \
            poet enclave basename >> /poet-shared/poet-enclave-basename; \
        fi && \
        if [ ! -f /poet-shared/simulator_rk_pub.pem ]; then \
            cp /etc/sawtooth/simulator_rk_pub.pem /poet-shared; \
        fi && \
        while [ ! -f /poet-shared/validator-0/keys/validator.priv ]; do sleep 1; done && \
        cp -a /poet-shared/validator-0/keys /etc/sawtooth && \
        poet registration create -k /etc/sawtooth/keys/validator.priv -o /poet-shared/poet.batch && \
        poet-engine -C tcp://validator-0:5050 --component tcp://validator-0:4004 \
    \""

  poet-validator-registry-tp-0:
    image: hyperledger/sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp:1.1
    container_name: sawtooth-poet-validator-registry-tp-0
    expose:
      - 4004
    command: poet-validator-registry-tp -C tcp://validator-0:4004
    environment:
      PYTHONPATH: /project/sawtooth-core/consensus/poet/common
    stop_signal: SIGKILL
```

[image]

I found some errors here, but how to fix these?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a minimum of two Transaction Processors per node to make the PoET work.

I have the same type of setup; but I am running TP's in Kubernetes and have three replica set(s) per Node in the network.

Besides look at the validator.toml and make sure that you have the bind to network 0.0.0.0, I have tried to bind it to a specific NIC ip and it does not work. Only 0.0.0.0 (all ips) seems to work fine.